# php compiler to compare code?

Tags: php, compare

We have a codebase of php scripts that we want to convert to a new coding convention. We are looking at automated beautifying to convert scripts to the new standard. We'd like to make double sure that the code still works as it originally did. We can use `php -l` on the command line to make sure that there are no errors, but we'd like to go to the next step to make sure that the old formatted is functionally the same as the new.

Is there a way we can compile binaries or whatever from both the old and the new to ensure that they are identical? I'm assuming that indentation, line breaks, etc are ignored in a compiled form?

Comment: Where are your [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)?

Comment: Really, what you should have had (and write them now if you didn't) is unit-tests that will indicate if any of the behavior changes. That way, you can make ANY changes to the codebase and still know if it all works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the php bytecode with bytekit-cli [(blogpost)](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/871-bytekit-cli.html) / [(github project)](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/bytekit-cli).

To see if your new and old code produces the same php-bytecode. Knowing that you can be pretty sure everything will work. (If you are using annotations i'm not to sure how that works out with that)

Comment: In short (and in php context): If you have programmaticly relevant stuff in comments and some other part of the programm scans that comment to see if it has to to something. (like the @expectedException stuff in phpunit).

Answer (score 2):

Call [token_get_all](http://docs.php.net/token_get_all) on the old and the new script and compare the results taking your changes (added/removed spaces, tabs, curly braces, even comments and commata at certain places) into account.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [phc](http://phpcompiler.org). Parse each file and produce XML output, and compare the XML output before and after.

```
phc --dump-xml filename.php
```

Of course, part of the problem might be that your beautifier does not use a real parser, and so can be faulty (I don't know, I haven't looked at it). phc has a `--pretty-print` option that is based on a real parser, so you might have better luck with it.